# Any benefit for analyzing the depth of craters across the surface of a planet?

Tags: data-analysis, crater

I would like to know what conclusions one could draw from mathematically analyzing the depth of various craters across the surface of a given planet, and then relating that to their position on said planet. Note that I am not looking for immediate conclusions, but rather conclusions that could actually benefit manned exploration in that region. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure there's a good answer to this question. Astronomers study the distribution, number, size, and depth (when possible) of craters on various bodies, but as far as I know, the nature of that study is to help understand geologic processes on that body, e.g., how old is the surface? I'm not sure knowing the age of the rock comprising the surface of any given body benefits manned exploration. Once could study a particular crater in-depth to help in navigation by explorers, but that isn't the type of studying you're proposing in your question.